# Php preg_match pattern

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a form field that I want to check if the user submitted a correct pattern. I tried it this way.

```
// $car_plate should in XXX-1111, or XXX-111(three letters in uppercase followed by a dash and four or three numbers)
<?php
    $car_plate = $values['car_plate'];
    if (!preg_match('[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3|4}$', $car_plate)) {
        $this->errors ="Pattern for plate number is XXX-1111 or XXX-111";
    } else {
        // code to submit
    }
?>
```

The following car_plate numbers is in correct format (AAA-456, AGC-4567, WER-123). In this case it always return the error. What is the correct way?

Comment: {3|4} ==={3,4} .....

Comment: @Starkeen, I thought | is accepted as Or (3 OR 4)in preg_match.Your suggestion works.

Comment: the `|` (or) operator does not work in a frequency declaration, that is, within curly brackets {}. `{2}` = occurring exactly 2 times ::  `{1,}` = occurring 1 or more times (shortcut is `'+'`) :: `{3,4}` = occurring 3 to 4 times :: `{3,6}` = occurring 3 to 6 times -- u can SAY it like this "3 or 4 or 5 or 6 times", but you WRITE it in a regular expression {3,6} -- it's the same thing as writing "3-6 times" in everyday use.

Comment: @Starkeen in a regular expression {3|4} !== {3,4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're a little bit off with your regular expression.

Try this one:

```
/^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3,4}$/
```

In PHP, you have to enclose your regular expression with [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), in this case the slashes. In addition to that, `{3|4}` is not valid, the correct syntax is `{3,4}` as you can see in the docs covering [repetition](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.repetition.php).

Comment: I realise it works out as the same in this scenario, but it should be clarified that `{3,4}` means "between 3 and 4", and not "3 or 4" as the OP was attempting.

Answer (score 2):

alternative to TimoSta's answer.

`/^[a-zA-Z]{3}-?\d{3,4}$/`

this allows for user to enter letters in lowercase and to skip the dash

you can format the data later like this:

```
$input = 'abc1234';
if ( preg_match( '/^([a-zA-Z]{3})-?(\d{3,4})$/', $input, $matches ) )
{
    $new_input = strtoupper( $matches[1] ) . '-' . $matches[2];
    echo $new_input;
}
```

outputs: ABC-1234